# Store additional session data with custom auth driver

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I created a custom Auth driver for my Laravel app. Now I'm wondering what would be the standard way to add additional data to my auth session.

I created a custom guard:

```php
class MyAppGuard extends Guard {
    //...
}
```

A user provider:

```php
class MyAppUserProvider implements UserProviderInterface {
    //...
}
```

I've registered my driver in `global.php`:

```php
Auth::extend('mydriver', function($app) {
    $provider = new \MyApp\Auth\MyAppUserProvider($app['hash'], 'User');
    return new \MyApp\Auth\MyAppGuard($provider, $app['session.store']);
});
```

Everything seems to work fine, I can call custom methods of `MyAppGuard` with `Auth::myCustomMethod()` and so on and so forth.

I now want to add all the permissions for the user to the session so that they are accessible over `Auth::permissions()` like the user is over `Auth::user()`.

How should I do this, I'm sure I could do it in some ugly way but there must be a best practice?

Comment: How you checked the API's?

Answer (score 1):

In your provider class do something like:

```
 public function permission()
 {
     // get the id of the authentication users session
     $id = $this->session->get($this->getName());

     // now do a query to get the users permission by his/her id
     $permission = ...

     return $permission;
 }
```

Call it like

```
 Auth::permission();
```

If you review the code of Laravel Auth. It makes a new user model every time `Auth::user();` is called except if it is the same request then they just return the existing data immediately.

The only thing they store in the session is the user id. So I won't suggest using sessions to store your permissions. Just use the existing userid from the session and make a query for the permission then return the data.

From `Guard.php` you can access the users identifier like:

```
$id = $this->session->get($this->getName());
```

Note: I am not an expert.

### update

Add something like:

```
protected $permission;
```

Then set it like

```
$this->permission = $permission;
```

This is the same approach laravel is using for `Auth::user()`. I don't think it will be slow down you application.

Then in your `permission()` function do a check if the `$this->permission` is already set.

```
if (!is_null($this->permission))
{
     return $this->permission;
}

// then do the rest here like getting the permission
...
```

This way if the permission already exist for the request then it returns it rather than doing the whole query again (the part that could make it slow).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I've allready tried something quite similar, couldn't get it to work though. Would really like to omit the db query for each request. Also because the query is quite complex (3-4 joins). So I either store the permission data in the session or the cache. I'm not sure what's better, session makes more sense I guess. I'm going to try it again tomorrow.

Comment: Mhh the part where I think I failed was storing the actual data in the session. Retrieving the data again for each request and storing it in the object actually worked quite well. Also tried `$this->session->put('permissions', $permissions);`. But can't give you a real feedback until tomorrow.

Comment: Oh you saw my previews answer with the suggestion to store it in a session? hehe. After awhile I changed my mind to not do that because of security precautions so I edited my answer. You'd notice I have a lot of edits because I was also learning while I was trying to answer. :) Good luck.

Comment: Learning while trying to answer is the best thing of SO :)

Comment: agreed. Hope to get some feedback on which method actually went better :)

Answer (score 1):

The existing Guard class gives you all the tools you need for this.

**Requesting a relationship on a model caches the relationship, and the logged-in user's model is what's stored in the session data.**

Make use of the existing user() function, which checks for a current logged in user or a remember-me cookie, and then stores the session data.

Inside of MyAppGuard:

```
public function permissions() {
  if ($user = $this->user()) {
    return $user->permissions;
  } else {
    return $user;
  }
}
```

There's no need to eager-load the permissions into the user model. Since calling permissions() caches the relationship into the logged-in user model, the data is stored in the session.

You COULD eager-load the permissions by overriding the setUser() function

```
public function setUser() {
  parent::setUser();
  $this->user->load('permissions');
}
```

That would store the permissions into the session data as soon as the user logs in, as opposed to caching the permissions the first time that the permissions() function is called. But, it really makes no difference.

---

As a sidebar, none of this is technically necessary. If you were to call Auth::user()->permissions at any point in your code, you would cache the current logged in user's credentials in the current session. So an Auth::permissions() function is kind of pointless.

Comment: Thanks. The only problem with this is that I can't just load the relationship because my permission system is a bit more complex. I need to get different permissions for different objects. There is a function which generates the array of permissions. But maybe I can still somehow add it to the user to use the existing remember functionality.

Comment: @MarcelGwerder Exactly. That's pretty much what I'm trying to explain (even without eager-loading). The User model is what's stored in the session. So the simplest way to track the Permissions data is to store it in the User model. That's the proper way of handling these things.

Comment: From what I can see when looking at the `user()` code the user id is the only thing stored in the session. The actual user model is pulled from the database once per request over `$user = $this->provider->retrieveByID($id)` so attaching the permissions to the user in `setUser` would not store them in the session. Or do I overlook something...